# How to get all the required values using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I am having 2 kendo grids which are coming dynamically and the rows and the columns in the
grid are also coming dynamically.I have only single save button at the end of grids.

My question is when i click the save button i want to save all the values that are modified
in the grids. Hope you understand my question.How can i able to do that.Can any one please
provide me help

Thanks and Regards,
Srinivas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have something like:

```
var grid1 = $("#grid1").kendoGrid({...}).data("kendoGrid");
var grid2 = $("#grid2").kendoGrid({...}).data("kendoGrid");

$("#save_both").click(function() {
    grid1.saveChanges();
    grid2.saveChanges();
});
```

Basically, when the button is clicked you invoke the `saveChanges` method of both grids (see  http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#savechanges for more information on `saveChanges`).

Comment: In the each grid i am giving some radio buttons,question etc in the display mode directly. The grid should not be edited. When i click the radio button for the particular question the answer should be in the columns like radio button. I want to save all the questions and answers to the database.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I understood your question but reading your comment I see that I didn't and I don't. What I have explained is how to force saving modified data in two grids when you click an HTML element identified by "save_both". Now, you save that the grid "should not be edited" but it has "radio buttons" that you can click... Click a radio button is editing it!!!